# I am getting the error 'redefined-outer-name'

Tags: python

When running my lint, I am getting the error below:

```
Redefining name 'tmp_file' from outer scope (line 38) (redefined-outer-name)
```

Here is my snippet of code in that line:

```
tmp_file = open('../build/' + me_filename + '.js','w')
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

That happens because you have a local name identical to a global name. The local name takes precedence, of course, but it hides the global name, makes it inaccesible, and cause confusion to the reader.

**Solution**

Change the local name. Or maybe the global name, whatever makes more sense. But note that the global name may be part of the public module interface. The local name should be local and thus safe to change.

Unless... your intention is for these names to be the same. Then you will need to declare the name as `global` in the local scope:

```
tmp_file = None

def do_something():
    global tmp_file # <---- here!
    tmp_file = open(...)
```

Without the `global` declaration, the local `tmp_file` will be unrelated to the global one. Hence the warning.

Comment: I used `global` to re-assign my outer scope variable. But `linter` warns me: **W0603: using the global statement**

Comment: nice catch! i think the easiest solution is add _ the beginning of var name like for my case addr -> _addr

Answer (score 30):

## Solution

Create `main()` function which be holding all the main logic etc.

```
def pow(x):
    return x ** 2

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def main():
    x, y = 2, 4
    print(pow(x))
    print(add(x, y))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Explanation

This works, because every new function instance creates a new local scope.

Comment: I think this is a really useful option, as renaming variables that mean the same just because you use it in a different function does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 7):

#### Open with `with`

Apart from [@Rodrigo's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25000042/1587329) about scopes: if your `tmp_file` is just that, a temporary file, you can use

```
with open('../build/' + me_filename + '.js','w') as tmp_file:
    # do something
```

in both cases. It clearly defines where your `tmp_file` is going to be used.

It is [the recommended way](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) of dealing with variables whose scope needs to be clearly bounded.

#### Error description

Pylint has a built-in description:

```
pylint --help-msg=redefined-outer-name
```

gives

> :redefined-outer-name (W0621): *Redefining name %r from outer scope
> (line %s)*   Used when a variable's name hide a name defined in the
> outer scope. This   message belongs to the variables checker.

Answer (score 3):

You get this error if you have defined the same variable in multiple places like outside the def and inside the def.

If you are using the single variable define it as `global variable_name` and use global keyword all the places. Else please rename the other variables.

Comment: the variable being defined in def and outside df was my issue